# Sierra Wireless AirPrime Issue

Tags: ppp, qualcomm, libqmi

Facing a bit of issue with Sierra Wireless AirPrime EM7430. It's added in device which has internal sim slot and USB ports as well. The device has Ubuntu 14.04 OS server and we SSH to it. Now, for the USB port, I can connect modem ( using libqmi-utils) , device file cdc-wdm0 will be created, interface wwan0 will  be added and IP address can be assigned to it.

However, with the internal sim slot, we insert sim and no device file looks to come up. Nothing comes in dmesg. We have tried loading GobiSerial, GobiNet for it and ran wvdial. However, just the interface ppp0 will be created and no IP address assigned to it. On further review, it looks like ppp does not work with GobiSerial in a proper way.

Could someone please guide me towards what needs to be done? Any additional information needed, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide us the exact steps to replicate the problem

Comment: Hi jrswgtr, device has internal sim slot. For 3g/4g modem inserted through USB port, the device file /dev/cdc-wdm0 is added. I am looking if same sort of file will be added if sim is inserted to the sim slot. May be I am looking in the wrong direction.